# U-Boot bootcmd (auto vs manual)

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I'm running into an issue where when I power up my device, it hangs at

```
Starting kernel ...
```

Or it loops with

```
Starting kernel ...

resetting ...
```

However, if I interrupt the boot process and manually run boot, ie:

```
=> run bootcmd
or
=> boot
```

then the kernel loads fine.

According to DENX (5.9.6.5) this is equivalent to what Uboot should be doing automatically.

Does anyone know if there is a difference between letting uboot run on it's own and interrupting and running boot manually? Otherwise, how do I start debugging this?

ENVIRONMENT

```
=> printenv
autoload=no
baudrate=115200
board_name=EVK
board_rev=pilot
boot_fdt=try
bootcmd=echo Booting from network ...; usb start; setenv ethact asx0; if dhcp && tftp $loadaddr $bootfile && tftp $f
dt_addr $fdt_file; then run nfsboot; else echo WARN: Issue with TFTP.; run sdboot; fi;
bootdelay=3
bootfile=zImage
bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc ...; source
console=ttymxc1
ethact=asx0
ethprime=FEC
fdt_addr=0x83000000
fdt_file=imx6ul-pilot-v1-evk.dtb
fdt_high=0xffffffff
image=zImage
initrd_high=0xffffffff
ip_dyn=yes
loadaddr=0x80800000
loadbootscript=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${script};
loadfdt=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${fdt_addr} ${fdt_file}
loadimage=fatload mmc ${mmcdev}:${mmcpart} ${loadaddr} ${image}
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=${console},${baudrate} root=${mmcroot}
mmcautodetect=yes
mmcboot=echo Booting from mmc ...; run mmcargs; if test ${boot_fdt} = yes || test ${boot_fdt} = try; then if run loadfdt; then bootz ${loadaddr} - ${fdt_addr}; else if test ${boot_fdt} = try; then bootz; else echo WARN: Cannot load the DT; fi; fi; else bootz; fi;
mmcdev=1
mmcpart=1
mmcroot=/dev/mmcblk1p2 rootwait rw
netargs=setenv bootargs console=${console},${baudrate} root=/dev/nfs ip=dhcp nfsroot=${serverip}:${nfsroot},v3,tcp
nfsboot=run netargs; bootz $loadaddr - $fdt_addr
nfsroot=/nfs/rootfs
script=boot.scr
sdboot=echo Booting from mmc ...; mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then if run loadbootscript; then run bootscript; else if run loadimage; then run mmcboot; else echo ERROR: Cannot run loadimage; fi; fi; else run ERROR: Cannot run mmc rescan; fi;
serverip=192.168.0.219

Environment size: 1714/8188 bytes
```

Comment: Default command for booting is defined at compile stage. Your U-Boot might have been compiled using different command sequence than plain `run bootcmd`.

Comment: Do you know where in the source I can find the default command for booting?

Comment: Your assumption that autoboot and the `boot` or `run bootcmd` commands should be equivalent are correct.  But there are alternate variables, such as **altbootcmd** and **failbootcmd**.  Post the U-Boot environment variables, as well as the boot logs of both circumstances so that we can be assured that you're not overlooking anything.   *"how do I start debugging this?"* -- Insert `#define DEBUG 1` at the top of **common/autoboot.c** (and recompile) to enable the printout of the **bootcmd** (string) variable prior to its execution.

Comment: @DanielBujak -- The other comment is wrong.  U-Boot commands can be enabled or disabled by configuration, but not redefined (unless code is modified).  The various environment variables, especially **bootcmd**, can be assigned a default value.  But each variable can have only one value, so once you change (and save) a variable, the default value is gone (unless the saved environment is found to be invalid).

Comment: @sawdust, before judge other comment check the sources. One may or may not define a default command line which will be used for automatic boot by default.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I've rebuilt with the debug flag set but I see no difference in the logs. In any case I've attached the U-boot logs and environment

Comment: The environment printout is incomplete; long lines have been truncated.  (If you're using minicom, then you need to enable linewrap.)  Double check your build. Use the **strings** and **grep** commands to confirm that the debug text (i.e. "### main_loop: bootcmd") has been compiled into **autoboot.o** and **u-boot.bin** files.  The salient code is http://elixir.free-electrons.com/u-boot/v2016.03/source/common/autoboot.c#L359

Comment: Oops I missed that. I've updated the environment dump (now with debug enabled). I couldn't see the debug strings until I moved the DEBUG flag  to include/common.h. However, there are a ton of logs now so I'm trying to sort through them.

Comment: *" I couldn't see the debug strings until I moved the DEBUG flag to include/common.h."* -- That's not the proper way to define DEBUG globally.  Use CFLAGS in the **Makefile**.  But global DEBUG is too verbose, and that's why I enabled only the one salient file.  My instruction is accurate, as I have used the same; you must have done something incorrectly.  But it may be for naught; it should show the same bootcmd, but not reveal why the execution differs.  The boot sequence is so full of `if ...` and `run ...`, and it's not obvious what is temporal.

Comment: @0andriy -- You should heed you own advice. You seem to be be reciting only what's in the documentation or README file, and seem oblivious as to how it's actually implemented. Autoboot has the equivalent of `run bootcmd` *hardcoded*.  Regardless, there's no configuration to redefine U-Boot CLI commands.  CONFIG-BOOTCOMMAND only affects the environment variable **bootcmd**, not redefine commands `boot` or `bootd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was with the SDBOOT env var:

```
sdboot = echo Booting from mmc ...; mmc dev ${mmcdev}; mmc dev ${mmcdev}; 
         if mmc rescan; then 
             if run loadbootscript; then 
                 run bootscript; 
             else 
                 if run loadimage; then 
                     run mmcboot; 
                 else 
                     echo ERROR: Cannot run loadimage; 
                 fi; 
             fi; 
         else 
             echo ERROR: Cannot run mmc rescan; 
         fi;
```

Load bootscript kept failing with "** Unable to read file boot.scr **". I'm still not sure what was causing the difference but removing the loadbootscript branch and going straight to loadimage fixed the issue.

Comment: Via the logic if the script were failing at the loadbootscript line then it should continue into the else and do the loadimage anyway.  So the loadbootscript  must have succeeded and that message is coming from the bootscript line.